Calculation of value of supply in gst
The total sales according to invoices is 3 lakh, but I received 10 lakh in the current account registered with GST.
What will happen and how will GST be calculated?

If the invoice doesn't match the actual sale amount, either someone made a mistake or someone is attempting fraud. If you invoiced someone for ... sorry, I'm not familiar with Indian(?) currency, 300,000 rupees? but whatever, you billed them 3 and they paid you 10, then you need to get this straightened out and make the invoice match the actual payment.
At that point, GST will be based on the actual sale price.
If this is common in India, that the amount invoice does not match the amount paid, and this is completely legitimate, I'll gladly yield to someone who knows how things work in India.
